# Photo Competition: April - At Home in The Great Outdoors

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

Rules that are always applicable are as follows:

1. One photo per answer, and no more than 5 answers per user per contest.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself/person with you.
3. All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.
4. Refrain from posting sensitive/debatable content

---

Rules for April are as follows:

1. **At Home in The Great Outdoors. Photos of your campsite. People allowed.**
2. The contest will last the whole month of April and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself.
3. There is no constraint on when the photo must have been taken.

---

Suggest a theme for the next contest.

1. Leave a **single** comment below in the format
     THEME - ONE SENTENCE DESCRIPTION
2. Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next month.

Good luck!

Comment: DIY Gear - Gear that you have made yourself.

Comment: Contrast - Opposites occurring in nature

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple of years ago, I spent a week exploring the east coasts of Benbecula and South Uist, and took this photo of one of my overnight camp sites, looking back north along the coast I'd just paddled.  On a calm evening like this, there's no need for all six guy lines; one each side is enough to prevent condensation spots.

[image: camping by the sea]

Taken [close to the start of the track to Ushenish Lighthouse](https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=57.3007361&mlon=-7.2201500&zoom=14#map=15/57.2984/-7.2180) on Tuesday 24th May 2016.

Answer (score 8):

Norway 2013, Dovrefjell. My first 2-week hiking tour, with rather improvised gear. Instead of a tent, I just had a tarp, hiking sticks and paracord. With a bit of origami, it worked out well enough, and led to a great tour. The only day where it was too wet and mossy to camp that way, I was lucky and found a small cave instead. Needless to say, for the next tour I bought a tent...
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Sweden, in 2016, at the shores of [Fryken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fryken) near Karlstad.
Thanks to the allemansrätten, you can legally set up your tent on this beautiful patch of land and wake up in the morning right next to the lake and continue your hike.

In the summer, it also won't get much darker than this.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

July 2008 - we took the kids (aged 8, 6 and 1 - the elder two had the little blue tent, the baby slept in with us) camping round the UK from Cornwall to the Highlands.

This was in a lovely part of the Highlands called Strathconon - taken just as the afternoon was ending. Later on, the night was perfectly clear, the Milky Way providing the only light, and very little disturbing the silence.

[image]

Comment: I've never used such a big tent! O.o

Comment: Haha - those are two of our smallest tents. The big car camping tent can sleep up to twelve, and has a kitchen area and garage :-)

Comment: Garage.....?? O.O

Comment: Yup, so I could park the car out of the weather. It's not real camping, but it's great for a big family with young kids in places with really bad weather

Answer (score 6):

We spent 3 days at this base camp in the Laurentian mountains while backcountry skiing in march 2010. Every night we improved the lounge/kitchen pit that had a cooking counter, several cupboards, and seating for 8. The tent on the right built a pair of ornamental snow lions on their porch. Quite good fun!

[image: Nicest winter camp I ever had time to build]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting up a tent, one night I found a dry corner of a stone mine in which to spend the night.  Although dry, it was quite draughty at times, and I was happy to be on my way again early next morning.

[image: bivouac site]
Sunday 30th December 1990, [Wrengill Quarry](http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=54.4698500&mlon=-2.8123820&zoom=14), England.